# How to disable Web-Security / Change Response Headers in a Maui Blazor Hybrid Application WebView (C#)

Tags: c#, http, blazor, maui, hybrid

Im wondering if it is possible to disable the web security or change response headers for the Maui Blazor Webview. I am trying to display an iframe, however some websites do not allow to display it due to the X-Frame-Options Response Header, if I could disable web security or modify the response header I would be able to do that.

MauiProgram.cs:

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });


        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();


#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Tried searching around, but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the web security in Maui Blazor WebView, you can try to set additional arguments by setting an environment variable before calling `builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();` like below:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
        "WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS",
       "--disable-web-security");

        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
```

Comment: I have not heard from you for a while. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Comment: Hi, I have not tested your solution so far. I used Selenium to achieve what I wanted to achieve. So I did not need any I-Frames anymore.

Comment: @Kroks That's fine, thanks for the update!